# Prevent bash from printing “<PID> Aborted” messages

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a test script that runs a small app over and over again with various inputs:

```
# test_script.sh

for input1 in $some_range; do
    for input2 in $some_other_range; do
        if ! ./my_app $input1 $input2 2>/dev/null; then
            echo "ERROR: app failed with inputs: $input1 $input2"
        fi
    done
done
```

This is all well and good, except when it fails I get two messages, the 'ERROR' message I want, and then another (apparently from bash?) alerting me that my app was aborted:

```
test_script.sh: line 10:   641 Aborted           ./my_app $input1 $input2
ERROR: app failed with inputs: XXX YYY
```

**How do I prevent the 'Aborted' messages?**

Also note: The app is probably failing on a standard C library 'assert' statement.

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but error message should go to stderr, so your echo should be redirected.  e.g. 'echo "ERROR ..." >&2'

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this too.  It seems that `bash` itself prints this unilaterally if a child process returns with status code 134, indicating the child recieved `SIGABRT`.  The solution is to run the child process in a subshell, then ensure the *subshell* returns a different (still non-zero) status code on failure and has its output redirected to `/dev/null`.  For example:

```
if ! ( ./myapp || false ) >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Ingenious.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling job control:

```
set +m
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$()` to wrap your commands, for example:

```
$($app &> /dev/n
```

Comment: Does your answer maybe need finishing?

Comment: $($app &> /dev/null)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not suppress the error message.  Instead of having your script emit an error message and suppress the error from the app, have the script say nothing and let the app's error message print.  If you don't like the error message from the app, fix it in the app rather than trying to have the script patch it.

Answer (score -1):

you can  redirect stderr to `/dev/null`

`./myapp .... 2>/dev/null`

Comment: I am already redirecting the command's stderr to /dev/null; I will update the question.  The message seems to be coming from bash, not the application, since it specifies the line number of the aborted process.