# Suppress signal output like "Abort trap: 6" in a shellscript, for a test that should crash

Tags: macos, bash, testing, terminal, signals

Something helpfully outputs **Abort trap: 6** when a program crashes, that is started from a bash:

```
$ ./crash-if-correct > /dev/null 2>&1
Abort trap: 6
```

For a test case that should be crashing, this creates output that looks wrong. How can this be suppressed ?

I suspect it's not the shell (in my case that's bash), because an `ack 'trap:'` through the bash sources revealed nothing.

Simple way to reproduce:

```
$ cat <<EOF > abort.c
main()
{
   abort();
}
EOF

$ cc -w -o abort abort.c
$ sh -c ./abort > /dev/null 2>&1
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to run the child process in a subshell :

```
$ cc -w -o abort abort.c
$ $(./abort)
$
```

This works for me on OSX.

Note that if `./abort` outputs text, it will be executed

```
$ cat hello-abort.c
main()
{
    puts("Hello");
    abort();
}
$ cc -w -o hello-abort hello-abort.c
$ ./hello-abort
Hello
Abort trap: 6
$ $(./hello-abort)
bash: Hello: command not found                   # <== Danger
$ exec 3>&1; $(./hello-abort >&3); exec 3>&-
Hello
$
```

In zsh, the return value of the last command is 134. Append `|| true` to the command to make it become 0.

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912000/prevent-bash-from-printing-pid-aborted-messages)

Comment: This works for me. It's curious, because without the dollar it doesn't. But  shouldn't that be a subshell as well ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. Please check out the edit too - text would be executed with initial answer

Comment: What does `3>&1` do ? I've never seen it. If I do `if ./hello-abort ; then true ; else false ; fi 2> /dev/null` then your executable works and doesn't print the Abort trap: 6 message.

Comment: `3>&1` does create a file descriptor 3, and redirect it to the standard output. `3>&-` closes the file descriptor. Your solution does also work, and is neater

Comment: Actually `sh -c "( ./abort )" 2> /dev/null` is all it takes. I think Terminal.app then doesn't recognize it as a top level anymore or so.

Answer (score 1):

This message is generated by your shell, which communicates this way that a child process ended abnormally. Run it this way:

```
sh -c ./crash-if-correct > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Running this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    abort();
    return 0;
}
```

I got following output when not embedding in additional shell:

```
$ ./a.out > /dev/null 2>&1
Aborted (core dumped)
$
```

And here is the output when using additional shell:

```
$ sh -c ./a.out > /dev/null 2>&1
$
```

Comment: This does not work, it also produces the signal output. I will update my question with a simple example.

Comment: Well, I wrote similar program as you (calling abort function) and running it inside another shell produces no output. What OS/shell are you using?

Comment: Funny. As I wrote in the question, I am using bash. (Inside Terminal.app in OS X)

Comment: @user3093235: So this looks like special OS X behavior to me... I've added examples how `abort` function behaves in my bash inside `terminator` terminal under Ubuntu 12.04. Of course it changes nothing, so it looks I'm unable to help. Sorry.

Comment: Np. In the grand scheme of things, it's not a big problem anyway. Your solution works on linux, but I suppose Terminal.app on OS X interferes with me here. If I make it to 15 reps, you'll see I gave you a plus :)

Comment: To make this answer useful, you should document which implementation your `sh` is. Is it bash, dash, FreeBSD, NetBSD, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, and which version? There are a lot of differences in this area, see my answer for a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

Simply putting the aborting process in a subshell didn't work for me, so I did some more experiments and finally succeeded.

Preparation:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' '#include <stdlib.h>' 'int main(void) { abort(); }' > crash.c

$ make crash
cc -O2    -o crash crash.c
```

Running the experiments with bash 5.0.18 on NetBSD:

```sh
$ ./crash
Abort trap (core dumped)

$ ./crash 1>out 2>err
Abort trap (core dumped)

$ (./crash) 1>out 2>err
Abort trap (core dumped)

$ (./crash && exit 0) 1>out 2>err

$ cat out err

$ (./crash && exit 0); echo $?
134
```

So the subshell plus the `&& exit 0` did the trick in the end. It completely suppresses the output, it is neither in `out` nor `err`. The exit status is properly reported though.

Running the same experiment with /bin/sh from NetBSD 9.99.88:

```sh
$ ./crash
[1]   Abort trap (core dumped) ./crash

$ ./crash 1>out 2>err
[1]   Abort trap (core dumped) ./crash >out 2>err

$ (./crash) 1>out 2>err
[1]   Abort trap (core dumped) (./crash)

$ (./crash && exit 0) 1>out 2>err

$ cat out err
[1]   Abort trap (core dumped) ./crash

$ (./crash && exit 0) 1>out 2>err; echo $?
134
```

The difference to bash is that the NetBSD /bin/sh preserves the output that the program crashed.

Running the experiments with `/bin/ksh` from NetBSD 9.99.88:

```sh
$ ./crash
Abort (core dumped)

$ ./crash 1>out 2>err

$ cat out err
Abort (core dumped)

$ (./crash && exit 0) 1>out 2>err; echo $?
134

$ cat out err
Abort (core dumped)
```

For the Korn shell, it already suffices to redirect the output. The full-blown portable solution works as well here.

In summary, to suppress the output, the crashing process has to be run in a subshell and not as the very last command in that subshell. The exact behavior depends on the shell.